# Equipment to measure the distance to a sound

Tags: acoustics

Do you know if there is some sort of equipment that can measure the distance to a sound?
What practical application can such an equipment have?
The reason I'm asking is because I just got an idea of how to make such a machine. But it's really not hard to figure out so I guess there already exists such things. I didn't find anything on google though.
Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to hear your idea, but there's not really a physics question here so it's off-topic for this sub-site. I don't know if there's an engineering stack exchange where it would fit better.

Comment: I agree. I found the engineering forum and will ask there.

Comment: Two or more microphones and a PC. Such systems are being used in US cities by law enforcement to detect gunshots.

Answer (score 1):

You can reasonably assume that whatever idea you have, it's been considered already. That's because the math is the same for all wave phenomena, and a course of classical mechanics shows you there aren't that many different ways of extracting distance information.

You can have parallax measurements (measuring angle differences), and in the case of coherent source, interferometry could help too (measuring delays to a few point detectors). This last one is probably the best bet for sound, as it's the same thing your ears are doing - if you have enough detectors, you can triangulate in the same way GPS finds your position. All you need to get time delays is to compute cross correlations of signals.

If wavelength is comparable to measured distances, you have a bunch of problems with the maximum possible accuracy you can get anyway (diffraction limit).